# Can't get my head around some lambda expressions in Java 8

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lambda, casting, java-8

I have this snippet of code that looks like this without using lambda expressions:

```
.map(new Function<List<Post>, List<Post>>() {
    @Override
    public List<Post> apply(List<Post> posts) throws Exception {
        return realm.where(Post.class).equalTo(DatabaseContract.PostTable.USER_ID, userId).findAll();
    }
})
.onErrorResumeNext(new Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<? extends List<Post>>>() {
    @Override
    public ObservableSource<? extends List<Post>> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        Log.d("rafael", throwable.getMessage());
        return getLocalPostsObservable(userId, page);
    }
})
```

Using lambda expression (converted using Intellij feature) it becomes:

```
.map((Function<List<Post>, List<Post>>) posts -> realm.where(Post.class).equalTo(DatabaseContract.PostTable.USER_ID, userId).findAll())
.onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
    Log.d("rafael", throwable.getMessage());
    return getLocalPostsObservable(userId, page);
})
```

What I don't understand that why the type casting in `map()` from `posts` to `Function<List<Post>, List<Post>>` in

```
(Function<List<Post>, List<Post>>) posts -> realm.where(Post.class).equalTo(DatabaseContract.PostTable.USER_ID, userId).findAll()
```

Where at the same time there's no type casting in the second expression:

```
throwable -> {
    Log.d("rafael", throwable.getMessage());
    return getLocalPostsObservable(userId, page);
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing the cast? What's the return type of `findAll()`?

Comment: @shmosel The strange thing is when I remove the cast it doesn't complain or anything, `findAll()` returns `RealmResults<Post>`

Comment: There *are* cases where the compiler’s type inference needs help and one way to do it, is by providing a casting context. If you can remove the cast without problems, this is not such a case, but who knows, which heuristic IntelliJ’s macro uses to decide whether to insert such a cast or not…

Answer (score 2):

> What's the return type of `findAll()`?

I'd bet on a `List<Post>`, according to the return type of the `Function<S, T>`.

My guess is that the cast to `Function<S, T>` is applied to the whole lambda expression, not only to the `posts` parameter nor its return value.

As for the reason of its presence, it might be to avoid an ambiguous call of `map(FunctionLike<S, T>)`; otherwise, it wouldn't be the first time that a code generation tool adds some useless stuff around.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `posts` that is casted, but the entire lambda expression and because it does not fail compilation we can deduce that `posts` is actually of type `List<Post>` and `findAll` is also returning `List<Post>`.

Could it be because of *chaining* methods like:

```
where(..).equalTo(..).findAll(..)
```

You can test if this is the case by taking that code inside a method that returns `List<Post>` and inside your lambda expression use that method instead. If intelli does not add a cast - the problem is there.